# Was bedeutet "Schneckattack" in der Jugendsprache?

Tags: meaning, slang

Ich hab im Fernsehen eine Gruppe von Jugendlichen gesehen, von denen einer das Wort *Schneck-Attack* verwendet hat.

Was versteht man darunter? Ich glaube nicht, dass es sich dabei um einen Angriff der langsam kriechenden Tiere handelt. :-)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

> Situation in der sich ein Junge
>   plötzlich mit mehreren attraktiven
>   Mädchen konfrontiert sieht.

Selbst ist mir dieser Begriff noch nie untergekommen.

Quelle [Mundmische](http://mundmische.de/bedeutung/7930-Schneckattack)

Answer (score 8):

["Schnecke"](http://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/Schnecke) bedeutet neben dem Weichtier umgangssprachlich auch ein hübsches junges Mädchen, ein nicht selten benutzter Begriff.

Pubertierende Jugendliche empfinden das Auftreten hübscher Mädchen mitunter als bedrohlich, was im zweiten Teil mit "Attacke" zum Ausdruck kommt.

Answer (score 2):

Ergänzend zu den obigen Antworten könnte man noch hinzufügen, dass dies offenbar vom englischen Ausdruck "sneak attack" = Überraschungsangriff abgeleitet sein dürfte.

Comment: Interessante Idee. Ich denke, ein Beleg für diese These könnte Deine Antwort weiter aufwerten :) Hast Du da was?

Comment: nein, nur meine Kenntnis der englischen Sprache und mein Erlebthaben anderer derartiger Verballhornungen