# Woher kommen die Wörter 'Schnecke' und 'Nacktschnecke' (in der Bedeutung Frau)

Tags: etymology, vocabulary

Es gibt viele Wörter für Frauen und normalerweise werden sie nach etwas schönem benannt. Auf Deutsch aber gibt es auch 'Schnecke' oder 'Schneckchen' und zwar in irgendeinem positiven Sinne. Erste Frage: Woher kommt dieser Ausdruck?

Es ist mir eingefallen, dass es auch das Wort 'Nacktschnecke' (also, 'ohne Schamhaare') gibt. Weshalb ist schon klar. Zweite Frage: Hat der Ursprung von 'Schnecke' etwas damit zu tun, dass viele Frauen heutzutage 'Nacktschnecken' haben?

Comment: Zur Bedeutung (nicht Etymologie) siehe auch http://german.stackexchange.com/questions/1311/was-bedeutet-schneckattack-in-der-jugendsprache

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**Schneck(e)** ist als Kosename für ein hübsches Mädchen seit etwa 1800 belegt. Andere Bedeutungen des Wortes "Schneck(e)", die möglicherweise zu diesem Gebrauch geführt haben könnten:

- die schneckenförmig über die Ohren geflochtenen Haare unverheirateter Mädchen
- das süße Gebäck (Rosinenschnecke)
- die Schnecke symbolisiert Häuslichkeit
- oder Schüchternheit (siehe Goethes Gedicht unten)
- im bairischen bedeutet "schneckeln" sich hübsch anzukleiden (belegt seit etwa 1800)
- die Ähnlichkeit der Vulva mit einer Nacktschnecke (belegt seit etwa 1800)

Zur Ähnlichkeit von Vulva und Schneckentier kann man noch hinzufügen, dass der Grund des sprachlichen Vergleichs nicht oder nicht allein auf einer visuellen Ähnlichkeit beruhen muss. "Schneck" ist in manchen oberdeutschen (süddeutschen und österreichischen) Dialekten auch eine Bezeichnung für Rotz, der von Kindernasen hängt, und die (beim Sexualkontakt gesehene) Vulva und die Schnecke haben vielleicht auch (oder vor allem) ihre Schleimigkeit gemeinsam.

Ein Gedicht von Goethe:

```
nicht immer gleich
ist ein galantes mädchen,
ihr herrn, für euch;
nimmt sich der gute freund zu viel heraus,
gleich ist die schneck' in ihrem haus.
```

Die Bezeichnung "Nacktschnecke" kenne ich erst aus jüngerer Zeit, sie hängt sicher mit der in den 1990er Jahren aufgekommenen Mode zusammen, die Schamhaare komplett zu rasieren. Noch in den 70ern oder 80ern war das fast völlig unüblich, und vermutlich auch um 1800 oder davor nicht sehr verbreitet ;-) Ich denke deshalb, dass sich die "Nacktschnecke" von der "Schnecke" ableitet, und nicht umgekehrt (wie die Eröffnungsfrage nahelegt).

*Quellen: Grimms Wörterbuch, Küpers Wörterbuch der deutschen Umgangssprache, mein Bäcker ;-)*

Comment: +1 für die Feldforschung beim Bäcker. Nicht zu vergessen der Schneckerl Prohaska, österr. Nationalspieler und wenn mich mein Gedächtnis nicht täuscht, beim Jahrhundertsieg über die Deutschen mit von der Partie.

Answer (score 1):

Im [Duden](http://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/Schnecke) stehen 'Vagina' und 'Loch' als Synonyme für 'Schnecke'.  Vermutlich ist 'Schnecke' dann nichts tieferes als ein vulgärer Ausdruck für Mädchen.

Answer (score 1):

Im [Pfälzer Wörterbuch](http://woerterbuchnetz.de/cgi-bin/WBNetz/wbgui_py?sigle=PfWB&lemid=PS04386) (dort unter 7., 8. - das automatische Layout macht hier daraus 1., 2.) finde ich:

> 1. a. 'das Geschlechtsorgan der Frau' [ [...]  KB-Kriegsf [...]  LU-Opp [...] 
>      NW-Freinsh [...]  Kallstdt,
>      Don-Schowe]; vgl. PfWB Schneckenwasser; Syn. s. PfWB Bunz. — 
>      b. 'ein Mädchen ohne Schambehaarung'; e blott Sch. [ [...]  KB-Kriegsf]. — 
>      c. 'Geschlechtsteil der Kuh' [ [...]  RO-Ebbg [...]  NW-Leistdt];
>      Syn. s. PfWB Schluß 1 a. —
> 2. Kosewort für ein Mädchen; du liewi Schneck! [Pirmas]. —

Das Geschlechtsteil der Kuh ist mir nicht weiter vertraut. Bislang gesammelt hätten wir also das Loch des Schneckenhauses, die Schamlippe als Schneckenkörper und dazu kommt noch der Schneckendutt als Kopfbehaarung der Mädchen, letzteres halte ich aber für nicht sehr wahrscheinlich.

Answer (score -1):

Eine Schnecke von unten hat wohl eine gewisse Ähnlichkeit mit den inneren Schamlippen der Vagina. Mit Nacktschnecke meint man umgangssprachlich eine rasierte Vagina. Schnecke sagt man nur zu einer Frau, bzw. nennt sie so, wenn man sie wirklich gut kennt, eher kumpelhaft.

Comment: Das behauptet ja nicht mal, dass die Ähnlichkeit auch wirklich Pate gestanden hat bei der Herkunft des Begriffs. Weißt Du, dass der Begriff auch daher kommt oder ist das nur eine Spekulation? So oder so sollte das aus der Antwort hervorgehen.